# Go to next matching page in Acrobat

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, find, adobe-acrobat

In Acrobat X, if I search for a term using Command-F, I can find each match by pressing enter. Is it possible to go to the next page containing the search term (rather than to the location of the term itself)?